# SQL for getting each category data in maria db

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to fetch 4 random values from each category. What should be the correct sql syntax for maria db. I have attached one image of table structure.

[Please click here to check the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE22V.png)

Should i write some procedure or i can do it with basic sql syntax?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE category_id = XXX 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 4
```

do it for all categories

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping me. I'm trying same but i am facing problem to collect all of records. It means i am not able to apply union all for these records.

Comment: (select * from hb_quiz_question as hb1 where hb1.category_id = 1 order by RAND() limit 4)
    union
    (select * from hb_quiz_question as hb1 where hb1.category_id = 2 order by RAND() limit 4)
    union
    (select * from hb_quiz_question as hb1 where hb1.category_id = 3 order by RAND() limit 4)
    union
    (select * from hb_quiz_question as hb1 where hb1.category_id = 4 order by RAND() limit 4)

Comment: Bad solution: Even if you use an index an index scan is performed over all rows just for getting one random value. With some thousand rows it will become incredible slow!

Comment: M getting total 16 records from this complete query but if i want only 10 records from complete data set then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a SQL statement if you only have a few rows:

```
SELECT id, question, ... FROM x1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

This works fine if you have only a few rows - as soon as you have thousands of rows the overhead for sorting the rows becomes important, you have to sort all rows for getting only one row.

A trickier but better solution would be:

```
SELECT id, question from x1  JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT(MAX(id)) FROM x1)) AS id) as id using(id);
```

Running EXPLAIN on both SELECTS will show you the difference...

If you need random value for different categories combine the selects via union and add a where clause

Comment: Thanks @Georg. I'll try to do the same from second solution but i have few records so i'll let it be but try to implement second solution too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#top_n_in_each_group

But then `ORDER BY category, RAND()`.  (Your `category` is the blog's `province`.)

Notice how it uses @variables to do the counting.

If you have MariaDB 10.2, then use one of its Windowing functions.